# Maintaining the size of a div that can be magnified

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can a div maintain it's printable layout while being able to be zoomed in on?

I've tried to make a div zoomable by using jQuery to affect the percentage of the height and width of a div with the ID of "page".

```
<div style="
height: 70%;
width: 70%;"
id="page">
```

The default is 70% width and 70% height, if the + button is pressed +5% is added to the height and the width (with a max of 100% height/width), and the inverse is true as well, if the - button is pressed -5% to height/width (min of 10% height/width).

When I try to convert the final product to a pdf the modified height/width doesn't return to the default and the content of the ID div either doesn't fit the pdf, or is far too small to read.

[image]

The effect I'm looking to achieve is mirrored on a site called zety.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@media print {
   #page {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
   }
}
```

EDIT:

If you're using jQuery to modify the `style` attribute directly, you may need to add `!important` to the CSS rules. I would recommend using jQuery to modify the CSS of the div#id, not the html style attribute:

`$("#page").css("width",70%);`